# Heap allocation error within static library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have a working Visual Studio project.

I've created a static library with the files of the original project (except main.cpp), also
I've created a "tester" project (with the static lib linked to it) with only a main.cpp file from the original project.

Both compiles without any relevant error.
And tester runs appropriately.

But! At testing the "tester" I am getting a heap allocation error at a (not the first)
new[] operator invoked in a constructor implemented in the library.

That line working fine in the original project without any error.

The "little" version of the code:

```
//the staticlib
void test() {
 manager* m = new manager;
 m->open();
}
//....
class manager {
public:
open() {

        PRAWINPUTDEVICELIST lDevList;
        UINT lDevCount;
        GetRawInputDeviceList(NULL, &lDevCount, sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICELIST));
        lDevList = (PRAWINPUTDEVICELIST) malloc(sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICELIST)*lDevCount);
        GetRawInputDeviceList(lDevList, &lDevCount, sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICELIST));


        if(lDevCount) {



            for(UINT i = 0; i < lDevCount; i++) {


                HIDP_CAPS mCaps;
                PHIDP_BUTTON_CAPS mButtonCaps;
                PHIDP_VALUE_CAPS mValueCaps;

                UINT size;
                GetRawInputDeviceInfo(lDevList[i].hDevice, RIDI_DEVICENAME, NULL, &size);
                char* name = new char[size+1];
            //just to be sure
            memset(name, 0, size+1);
            //surely sure
            name[size] = '\0';
                GetRawInputDeviceInfo(lDevList[i].hDevice, RIDI_DEVICENAME, name, &size);



                HANDLE lDev = CreateFile((LPCWSTR)name, 0, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                                     NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);;

                PHIDP_PREPARSED_DATA lPrep;
                HidD_GetPreparsedData(lDev, &lPrep);
                HidP_GetCaps(lPrep, &mCaps);

                if(mCaps.NumberInputButtonCaps) {
                                    //crash is here below
                                    //mCaps.NumberInputButtonCaps ~1
                    mButtonCaps = new HIDP_BUTTON_CAPS[mCaps.NumberInputButtonCaps];
                    HidP_GetButtonCaps(HidP_Input, mButtonCaps, &mCaps.NumberInputButtonCaps, lPrep);
                }

                if(mCaps.NumberInputValueCaps) {
                                    //if the first "crash-line" is commented, then
                                    //the crash is here
                    mValueCaps = new HIDP_VALUE_CAPS[mCaps.NumberInputValueCaps];
                    HidP_GetValueCaps(HidP_Input, mValueCaps, &mCaps.NumberInputValueCaps, lPrep);
                }

                CloseHandle(lDev);      
            }


        } 
    }
};

//the app

test();
```

Where I am wrong? Is it a typical novice commission I am not afraid of?

Sorry for my English, and thanks ahead for your time!

Comment: I haven't used libraries a lot, but I know there are some cases where a library may use one heap, and the `main` another.  And objects can only be released in the heap they were allocated in, so it would cause problems.  I thought that was dynamic libraries though, I didn't think it applied to static libraries.  Otherwise this would be an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @Mooing Duck: Yes dynamic libraries only.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: I can't, it's kinda long.

Comment: If you want to get help with your code, then your best option is to cut it down until it is small enough to post here (and is still showing the bug of course). It's a lengthy exercise, but you will learn a lot, and may even solve the problem yourself.

Comment: @john: Okay, now it's cut down and the crash is still here.

Comment: You are allocating `size` chars. Perhaps it should be `size+1` instead. Things to check: Is the string null-terminated (most C-style `char` arrays are), and if so, are you accounting for that null character in the `size`?

Comment: @David Hammen: Okay, updated, but the crash still alive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is that you should be allocating wide chars when you call GetRawInputDeviceInfo. From the manual

> RIDI_DEVICENAME 0x20000007
>   pData points to a string that contains the device name.
>
> For this uiCommand only, the value in pcbSize is the character count
>   (not the byte count).

In other words you should write

```
wchar_t* name = new wchar_t[size];
GetRawInputDeviceInfo(lDevList[i].hDevice, RIDI_DEVICENAME, name, &size);
```

Just from reading the manual, I have no actual experience with this API, but it seems a likely explanation.

Comment: Also the fact that you had to add a cast to CreateFile - `CreateFile((LPCWSTR)name, 0, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);` should have been a clue. Unfortunately Windows code is often littered with unnecessary casts. All they do is mask errors.

Comment: Thanks! It solved the problem. :)
Me silly for not noticing the lpcWstr.

Comment: But I am still not understand, why the original project does work, and why VS can't point out the right source of error in that case.

Comment: It's called Undefined Behaviour (UB). When you make this kind of mistake the behaviour of your program is no longer guaranteed by the rules of C++. Many things can happen, including that your code appears to work, only for it to mysteriously fail when you try the same code in a different situation. Which of course is exactly what happened to you. Some languages have much less UB, Java is the obvious example, but they pay a price for this in efficiency terms. The best way of dealing with UB is to be aware of it and code carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Add logic that checks for error return states on every Win32 call you make. Possibly one of them is failing and when you remedy that, the rest will work.  **Always** check for and handle errors when you are using Win32 APIs.